# Initialize hashtable from array of objects?

Tags: powershell

I'm brand new to powershell, as in less than a day experience.  I have an array of objects returned from a `Get-ADUser` call. I will be doing a lot of lookups so thought it best to build a hashtable from it.

Is there a shorthand way to initialize the hashtable with this array and specify one of the object's attributes to use as a key?

Or do I have to loop the whole array and manually add to the set?

```
$adSet = @{}

foreach ($user in $allusers) {

    $adSet.add($user.samAccountname, $user)
}
```

Comment: That (`@{}`) is not a hash _set_ - it's a _hashtable_ - and looping through the input collection is indeed the way to go :-)

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [...] do I have to loop

### Yes

> ... the whole array ...

### No

You don't have to materialize an array and use a loop statement (like `foreach(){...}`), you can use the pipeline to turn a stream of objects into a hashtable as well, using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet - this might prove faster if the input source (in the example below, that would be `Get-Service`) is *slow*:

```
$ServiceTable = Get-Service |ForEach-Object -Begin { $ht = @{} } -Process { $ht[$_.Name] = $_ } -End { return $ht }
```

The block passed as `-Begin` will execute once (at the beginning), the block passed to `-Process` will execute once *per pipeline input item*, and the block passed to `-End` will execute once, after all the input has being recevied and processed.

With your example, that would look something like this:

```
$ADUserTable = Get-ADUser -Filter * |ForEach-Object -Begin { $ht = @{} } -Process { $ht[$_.SAMAccountName] = $_ } -End { return $ht }
```

---

Every single "cmdlet" in PowerShell maps onto this Begin/Process/End lifecycle, so generalizing this pattern with a custom function is straightforward:

```
function New-LookupTable {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [array]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Property
    )

    begin {
        # initialize table
        $lookupTable = @{}
    }

    process {
        # populate table
        foreach($object in $InputObject){
            $lookupTable[$object.$Property] = $object
        }
    }

    end {
        return $lookupTable
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
$ADUserTable = Get-ADUser |New-LookupTable -Property SAMAccountName
```

See the [`about_Functions_Advanced` document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) and related help topics for more information about writing advanced and pipeline-enabled functions

Comment: Thanks, this helps out a lot.

Comment: @Phaelaxz That's great, you're most welcome :) You might find [PSCache](https://github.com/IISResetMe/PSCache) interesting as well (uses a hashtable to cache items but allows for granular updates)

Comment: I wish PowerShell had something like Groovy's [`collectEntries`](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-transform-collection-to.html) method or your `New-LookupTable` built into it. BTW, you have a typo, `$PropertyName` should be `$Property`.

Comment: @zett42 thanks updated. Yeah, it'd be nice. I guess that's the price of co-opting any existing type system, it's all designed with C# or VB in mind,

Comment: @zett42, FYI, I did a purpose for this some time ago: [`#13817` Enhance hash table syntax](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13817)